# How to set "Display Product Options In:" to "Product Info Column" by default

Tags: php, custom-options, javascript, html

How to set `Catalog-> Manage Products-> X product-> Design-> Display Product Options In:` to `Product Info Column` by default.
i want apply it to all products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `catalog > manage products`. Select all or the ones you want. Action : `modify attributes`. And select the design you want for your selected items.

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. That doesn't set the default value of the attribute. I have just tried Antoine's answer and it works perfectly. If you then want to update the attribute for all products do a csv import; it's much quicker.

Comment: This does not set the default value of the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I managed it by changing attributes. Find Display Product Options in the attributes, simply type the desired excact name in the lable options and also select the default option.